# print key and only one value from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is the dictionary:

```
std[name]={'uid':uid ,'age':age,'subject':{'math':math,'phy':phy,'chem':chem}}
```

The output should be:

listing `name` and `uid`.

here is my code:

```
std={}
i=0
n=int(raw_input("How many Entries you have to fill:"))
for i in range (n):
   name=raw_input("Enter name:")
   uid=raw_input("ID:")
   age=raw_input("Age:")
   print("----Marks----")
   math=raw_input("Maths:")
   phy=raw_input("Physics:")
   chem=raw_input("Chemistry:")
   std[name]={'Uid':uid,'Age':age,'subject'{'math':math,'phy':phy,'chem':chem}}
   print('\n')
print(std['name']['uid'])
```

Comment: `print(std['name']['uid'])`?

Comment: Getting an error: 

print(std['name']['uid'])
KeyError: 'name'

Comment: that's because `name` is not defined earlier in your code

Comment: Name in your example isn't quoted - is it a variable? If so, you need to use it unquoted (or the quoted string it refers to) in your dict lookup.

Comment: Look at your post. The code is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `python 3.x` you can use:

```
for k,v in std.items():
    print(k,v['Uid'])
```

in `python 2.x`:

```
for k,v in std.iteritems():
        print(k,v['Uid'])
```

`python 3.x` code:

```
std={}
n=int(input("How many Entries you have to fill:"))

for i in range (n):
    name=input("Enter name:")
    uid=input("ID:")
    age=input("Age:")
    print("----Marks----")
    math=input("Maths:")
    phy=input("Physics:")
    chem=input("Chemistry:")
    std[name]={'Uid':uid,'Age':age,'subject':{'math':math,'phy':phy,'chem':chem}}
    print('\n')
for k,v in std.items():
    print(k,v['Uid'])
```

input and results for 2 different names will be:

```
How many Entries you have to fill:2

Enter name:John
ID:15895
Age:18
----Marks----
Maths:15
Physics:15
Chemistry:15


Enter name:Beck
ID:52256
Age:54
----Marks----
Maths:52
Physics:52
Chemistry:21


John 15895
Beck 52256
```